# add multiple files at once not working, GIT

Tags: git

git add *.filetype is not working on one of my projects. Works on every other project. Any ideas what can be wrong?[image]

Comment: Check the permissions/ownership of the files, I've been had by that a few times and it's so stupid it's never a thought of option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in a different folder from the changed files. As far as I know git just uses the shell's built-in expansion for this. If it has its own different expansion then I'm not sure why it doesn't work in this case.

Possible workaround (assuming this is a properly configured bash shell):

```
git add **/*.php
```

You might need to switch on the globstar shell config variable `shopt -s globstar` for this to work if it isn't already set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use old `find`/`xargs` trick to recursively add files of one extension (or any other mask for that matter):

```
find -name "*.php" -print0 | xargs -0 git add
```

If you are certain that file names never have any spaces, you can simplify this as:

```
find -name "*.php" | xargs git add
```